# How to include BarCode in PDF/A with iText7?

Tags: java, pdf, barcode, itext7, pdfa

I have been trying to generate PDFs with accessibility (PDF/A) but I am getting an error when closing the document saying that Font Helvetica is not embedded, despite the fact that I am putting font as null. the code is:

```
Barcode128 barcode = new Barcode128(pdfDoc);
barcode.setFont(null);
barcode.setCode(cell.getData());
barcode.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
...
PdfFormXObject xObject = barcode.createFormXObject(ColorConstants.Black, ColorConstants.Black, pdfDoc);
pdfCanvas.saveState();
pdfCanvas.rectangle(x, y, w, h);
pdfCanvas.restoreState();
pdfCanvas.addXObject(xObject, x, y);
```

Once I close the document it gives me the exception. If I remove the barcode code, the exception is not thrown. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed in [this](https://github.com/itext/itext7/commit/e94e438e9422e9b6a7499d6e17402c1141451f22) commit. The fix will be available in iText 7.1.6, but you can already use current development version, `7.1.6-SNAPSHOT`, from [Artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/snapshot/com/itextpdf) with the following Maven set up:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>itext-snapshot</id>
        <name>iText Repository - snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: The error states exactly that, indirect font is not embedded. I should have given the stack trace...

Comment: @MiguelArroja so, have you tried with 7.1.6-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: it works! Tried it myself and it's fine. Thank you so much! :D